# The collision detection works fine, but the score skyrockets, because multiple collisions occur. (pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection

In a squash game ( simular to pong, but with one player, and the ball bounces off the walls.) I have collision detection with the ball and the paddle and when they collide the score adds 1. I had a problem with the collision: when the ball hits the top or the bottom of the paddle it goes like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/88U9H.gif . I fixed that with ball.vx = -abs(ball.vx), and it looks like this now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIVgv.gif . Although the collision and the bouncing works good enough, when top or bottom collision happens, the score gets couple of numbers higher at once. If you see just the collision and ignore the score it's not noticeable at all, but more collisions happen at the same time and the score skyrockets.

```
hits = 0 

font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',25)
def Objects(paddle,ball,hits,font,black):
    temp = hits

  if ball.BallRect.colliderect(paddle.PaddleRect):
  
          ball.vx = -abs(ball.vx)
      
          score_text = font.render(f"Score: " + str(hits + 1),True, black)
          temp += 1 
  else: 
          score_text = font.render(f"Score: " + str(hits),True, black)
          window.blit(score_text,(20,20))

   return temp
 
  done = False 
  while not done: 
      hits = Objects(paddle,ball,hits,font,black=
      pygame.display.update() 
    
      clock.tick(120)
```

how do I fix the score ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only increment the score if ball moved to the right. This means that the score will only be increased if `ball.vx` is greater than 0. You need to do this before changing the direction of the ball (before changing `ball.vx`):

```py
def Objects(paddle, ball, hits, font, black):

    if ball.BallRect.colliderect(paddle.PaddleRect):
  
          if ball.vx > 0:
              hits += 1
          ball.vx = -abs(ball.vx)
      
    score_text = font.render(f"Score: " + str(hits), True, black)
    window.blit(score_text, (20, 20))

    return hits
```